# Jquery Ui Dialog calls every time on escape key press

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

Why does Jquery UI dialog called every time on escape key press? how to stop triggering open dialog on clicking escape?

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    // esc
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
          e.stopPropagation();
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for. Pass this as an option when you make your dialog

'$("#blah").dialog({closeOnEscape: false});'